# How to make Eclipse open code editor not in same pane as Project Explorer (again)?

Tags: eclipse

For the past several days, when I double-click files in the Package Explorer in Eclipse, the text/code editor is opening in the same pane as the Project Explorer.

It did not always behave this way.  It used to open the editor in a different pane or new pane.

How can I undo whatever I did?

Comment: This is not really a programming question.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta:  Yes.  I know.  It's a question about how I can improve my workflow in an extremely popular IDE, which I think qualifies as one of the three valid topics on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  Unless I'm misinterpreting something?

Comment: I know, I too need help in mastering it as it is so foreign to other IDEs I have used.  For now, I have suspended it :-)  I haven't downvoted you, but others might.

Comment: @RohitGupta Questions about software development tool problems are allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? there is the same question on http://superuser.com/questions/946687/eclipse-open-file-in-project-explorer-tab and I'm still searching ...

Comment: @Asoub: It has been a while, so I don't recall the details of what I did, but the workaround, essentially, was to start from scratch.  I may have just exported and then reimported my projects.  Or, I may have deleted my workspace, created a new one, and then imported my projects back into the new workspace (and made all my settings the way I like them).  In any event, I have not experienced the issue since.  Best of luck.

Comment: Wow, didn't thought I would get an answer ! Thank you very much. Setting upeclipse for my project is a real pain, I might try to restart from scratch it if that gets really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, Reset your perspective to default might help resolve this issue.

Window --> Perspective --> Reset Perspective